# Are VESA drills always exactly centered?

Tags: display, vesa

Let's say I have a 27" display with a 100×100 mounting and I'll buy another 27" display with a mounting. Then I have a display mount with two arms which are not individually height adjustable.

You probably already know where this is going. Will the panels be at the same height? Ignoring the bezels.

Comment: Centered compare to what? Screen? Monitor? Different displays may have different borders. Also top and bottom borders are sometimes different sized.

Comment: Centered to the panel. Sorry

Comment: In my experience, they are always centered horizontally, but not always vertically. Also, the screw holes are not always the same size.